# population and sample representation analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have one population data which has multiple categorical data and  multiple continuous data. I have 4 samples from this population. The sample is already created historically in my organization, so not aware how it is done. My job is to find which sample is the best representative of the population. I use python to work.

I read somewhere that  Pearson’s chi-square test to compare categorical variable and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for numerical variables. Just to mentioned, my variable types are float and object in python.

is there any way I can check which sample is the best representative of sample using python. Is there any way i can use for all the variable once and give me some statiscal significance..

Comment: Please follow stack overflow guidelines on questions. You should post an example of the code you have written to show what you have tried and a sample of the data for the community to replicate your use-case.

Comment: The answer for this question is logical one first, as I am not aware what method should be implemented. I am looking which method should be considered while having this problem then I can find how to solve it with the code. Hope that make sense

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good is a way to complete, but I have followed the did the t-test for continous variable and chi-square for categorical variable:

Code are followed:
batch1..batch4 are the available sample what I wanted to compare where is final_data is actual population here.
**

**- *t test for continuous variable in loop***

```
column = ["col1", "col2", "col3","col4"]
    for x in column:
        print("batch1 "+x+" "+str(stats.ttest_1samp(batch1[x], final_data[x].mean())))
        print("batch2 "+x+" "+str(stats.ttest_1samp(batch2[x], final_data[x].mean())))
        print("batch3 "+x+" "+str(stats.ttest_1samp(batch3[x], final_data[x].mean())))
        print("batch4 "+x+" "+str(stats.ttest_1samp(batch4[x], final_data[x].mean())))
```

***Chi square for categorical variable***

I made a function first

```
def pearsonChiSqGof(myData,field,exp=None):
    myFreq=myData[field].value_counts()
    df=len(myFreq)-1
    if exp==None:
        minE=sum(myFreq)/len(myFreq)
        chiVal,pval=chisquare(myFreq)
    else:
        minE=min(exp)
        chiVal,pval=chisquare(myFreq,exp)
        
    warning=None
    if minE<5:
        warning='minimum expected counl less than 5,chi-square test result not reliable'
    return chiVal,pval,df,minE,warning
```

then put a loop to run on all the columns

```
fieldList=[column list]

for x in fieldList:
    print("batch1 "+x+" "+str(pearsonChiSqGof(batch1,x)))
    print("batch2 "+x+" "+str(pearsonChiSqGof(batch2,x)))
    print("batch3 "+x+" "+str(pearsonChiSqGof(batch3,x)))
    print("batch4 "+x+" "+str(pearsonChiSqGof(batch4,x)))
```